# Plotly Spikes Not Appearing on Subplots

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I am making a figure with multiple subplots. I want each subplot to show spikes but am unable to get the spikes showing on anything other that the first subplot. I didn't see that ability to set showspikes with a fig.update_traces call. Any suggestions?

Code to reproduce:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

x1 = list(range(100))
y1 = [val**2 for val in x1]

x2 = list(range(150, 250))
y2 = [1./val for val in x2]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(showspikes=True))

fig.show()
```

Comment: This github issue seems relevant: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1677

Comment: Also this (scan for `showspikes` and `inside subplots`): https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Layout.html#plotly.graph_objects.layout.Modebar.uirevision

Comment: I tried setting ```uirevision=True``` to true but that didn't help. It says it should make changes persist across subplots and showspikes is included in the lists of things that persist so I'm not sure what's going wrong. True should be about as "truthy" as it gets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob's answer probably works, but you can achieve the same with:

```
fig.update_xaxes(showspikes = True)
```

Comment: Both do work (so I up-voted both) but this is the solution I was hoping for. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

- make sure you set **showspikes** on each of the axes.  Your figure contains **xaxis** and **xaxis2**
- code below uses a **dict** comprehension to update all if the axes

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)

x1 = list(range(100))
y1 = [val**2 for val in x1]

x2 = list(range(150, 250))
y2 = [1./val for val in x2]

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x2, y=y2), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout({ax:{"showspikes":True} for ax in fig.to_dict()["layout"] if ax[0:3]=="xax"})
```